# PHP Input array returning nothing when empty

Tags: php, arrays, post

So i'll try and explain this the best i can.

My form is generated by a loop. It's basically this

```
<input name="sheetQTY[]" type="number" min="0">
```

The problem i am facing is when you do not enter a number (needs to be an option). The post data returns nothing in the array for that input. I would like it to return an empty string.

Here is what i am getting.

```
[sheetQTY] => Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 5)
```

Here is what i want.

```
[sheetQTY] => Array ( [0] => '', [1] => 2, [2] => '', [3] => '', [4] => 5, [5] => '' )
```

Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: in the front end side you may validate the array before passing to server side in a loop where if the value of the input is null or nothing then assign the value as `""` for the respective key

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying but i believe that php would just see it as nothing and then treat it like it is now..

Comment: You could try in my way first as what i mentioned to insert an empty string because I haven try it before...
If it still work in the same way then you may assign a default sign such as `-` to indicate that it is not a number (**NaN**) then validate in the php side once the data is passed through